# What happens during a python module install? Can I just copy the module source to site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, m2crypto

I'm having trouble installing M2Crypto on my shared webhost account with pip. Can I just copy the module's source into site-packages, or does pip do something extra?

Comment: Some modules are purely script and some modules come with shared objects. The former can be copied straight to site-packages while the latter requires that the shared objects be placed in locations searched by ldconfig.

Comment: Really, there is no limit to what might happen when you install a package: the installer for a particular package can specify arbitrary code to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I have wondered the same thing in the past. However, I've had no problem installing packages "manually" by downloading them to my desktop, expanding them, then copying the appropriate objects to a sub-folder in my /extras directory (mine is a Django system). Be sure there is an **init**.py file in there, and I always ensure it will be added to my svn source control.